# The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query on a local query against linked tables

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to execute a SQL Select query that references linked tables in a backend database.

The query that I am trying to execute is saved as a query in the front-end database named: `HourlyDistinctMonitoringDates`.

`HourlyDistinctMonitoringDates` is defined as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT JobInstrumentId, 
                DATEVALUE(decibellog.readingdate) AS MonitoringDate, 
                HOUR(decibellog.readingtime) AS MonitoringHour
FROM jobinstrumentimport INNER JOIN decibellog ON jobinstrumentimport.id = decibellog.jobinstrumentimportid;
```

- The `decibellog` and `jobinstrumentimport` tables reside in a back-end (split) database.
- If I execute the `HourlyDistinctMonitoringDates` in a SQL View in Access from the front-end, it executes without any problem.
- If I execute the SQL Command that is built by my VBA in a SQL View in Access from the front-end, it executes without any problem.
- However, when I try to execute the following code; I obtain error 3078:
  `The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query on a local query against linked tables...`

  ```
    distinctDaysAndHours = "SELECT * FROM HourlyDistinctMonitoringDates WHERE jobinstrumentid=" & rstJobInstruments!id
    Set rstDistinctDatesHours = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(distinctDatesAndHours)
  ```
- When executed in VBA, the string: `distinctDaysAndHours` contains a SQL command such as:

  `SELECT * FROM HourlyDistinctMonitoringDates WHERE jobinstrumentid=10`

This command will execute if pasted into the SQL View in the Access Query Design.

So the problem is obviously in the use of:

- `CurrentdB.OpenRecordset`
- The query residing in the front-end instead of the back-end.
- Possibly both?

Comment: What is the problem?  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well, if _it executes without any problem_, then move on.

Comment: I too have difficulties figuring out what the problem is. Also what exactly is *in a SQL View in Access*?

Comment: The SQL View in Access is under the Query Design.  Right-click your query in the Navigation Pane.  Select the SQL View from the view button on the Query Design ribbon.  You can edit the SQL Query and run it.  In my case, I can take the SQL Command produced by my VBA and paste it into this view and execute it.

Comment: Ok. Running (incl. DB.OpenRecordset) queries that are saved in the frontend, but use linked tables, is perfectly normal. So this should work. Double-check all object names in VBA. Try to simplify the problem - run a `SELECT * FROM aVerySimpleQuery` in your code.

Comment: The SQL statement does work.  If I take the SQL Command prepared by my VBA, and run it in the Query Designer, it works without any problem.  This has to be an issue with executing a front-end query against back-end table with CurrentDb.OpenRecordset.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an error number, your answer is nearby
check microsoft website

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-engine-not-find-input-table

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a case where I am linking Access to Sharepoint.